# jquery syntax .css() with a var

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = "/someimage.png"
$('#client_bg').css("background", "url(foo)");
```

What is the proper syntax for this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS or jQuery. This is a basic question about whether Javascript supports variable interpolation in strings. Please get into the habit of decomposing problems. Which Javascript book are you using?

Answer (score 4):

```
var foo = '/someimage.png';
$('#client_bg').css('background-image', 'url(' + foo + ')');
```

or if you prefer:

```
$('#client_bg').css({ backgroundImage: 'url(' + foo +')' });
```